# Nvidia Geforce 210 on 12.04

Tags: installation, nvidia

The problem is that when I install the recomended drivers for the graphic card and next to that I reboot as the system says, the system loads so far and the screen turns off. I've tried several mothods but the problem persists.  Is an Nvidia Geforce 210 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing updated stable video drivers from the X Updates PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

For bleeding edge video drivers (which can contain bugs and break your system) there is the xorg-edgers PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Instructions to add the PPA's are on the websites. To remove them use the **ppa-purge** tool which can be installed from Ubuntu's repositories.